# Python program hangs when running socket.accept() in a different thread

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, networking, host

I am creating a simple implementation of a server socket in a separate thread. The issue is that the method is able to progress until invoking socket.accept() where the thread then hangs without accepting any connections. If you guys can see the issue that would be greatly appreciated :^) See below for more details:

**Method for creating a socket and accepting connections. EDIT: I also moved socket.listen() outside the loop as Mark Tolonen specified. EDIT2: I added a placeholder for the HOST and PORT settings as Mark Tolonen specified, which is a static IPv4 address and port (I did not provide the actual address for security reasons).**

```
HOST = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
PORT = 10063

def get_connection(address=HOST, port=PORT, socket_timeout=socket_timeout, conn_queue=conn_queue):
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.bind((address, port))
        logging.warning("Listening for clients...")
        s.listen()
        logging.warning("Client found, getting connection...")
        while True:
            try:
                conn, addr = s.accept()
                logging.warning(
                    "Connection found, putting connection into queue...")
                conn_queue.put({'conn': conn, 'address': addr})
            except:
                logging.error("No clients found...")
```

**Code for creating a thread for the above method and placing it into a deque, *threads*:**

```
socket_handler = threading.Thread(
        target=get_connection, daemon=True)
socket_handler.start()
threads.append(socket_handler)
```

**Sample output:**

> WARNING:root:Cleaning threads...
> INFO:root:<Thread(Thread-1, started daemon 8848)>
> WARNING:root:Listening for clients...
> WARNING:root:No inactive threads found.
> WARNING:root:Client found, getting connection...
> WARNING:root:Cleaning threads...

**The logs for the method stop at "Client found, getting connection..." which indicates to me that the program is hanging at s.accept():**

> WARNING:root:Client found, getting connection...

**EDIT: The below log was not output to the console which was the indication to me that the s.accept() call was not completed and was still blocking.**

> "Connection found, putting connection into queue..."

Comment: It's a bit hard to help you because, as is, you've just described normal behavior. `accept` is a blocking function, in the sense that it will "hang" until a client connects. When a client connects, it will almost instantly add its connection to `conn_queue`, loop back and block at `accept` again.

Comment: *""Client found, getting connection...""* - this message does not match anything in your code, which suggest that the code you show is not the code you are actually running. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich I made corrections to my post, thank you

Comment: @BlackBeans The indication to me that something is not functioning as expected is the absence of this log: "Connection found, putting connection into queue...". Since this log was not output, my thought process is that the s.accept() call was not completed and is still blocking.

Comment: `listen` should be outside the while loop.  It only needs to be called once after `bind`.  The log message after it is incorrect.  A client hasn't connected until `accept` returns.  `accept` *should* block until a client connects.

Comment: Do you even have clients that connect?

Comment: `s.accept()` waits until a client is connected, if not it will be paused there forever. The second thing is once the client is connected you don't have to wait again and again. So remove the while loop or just put `break` statement after `s.accept()`

Comment: @KavinduRavishka Thank you for the help! The reason I created the loop is to continually add new connections to a queue as they are discovered. The issue I'm running into is that the first loop does not complete as s.accept() is likely not returning a connection. As a result, I am not receiving the following log after calling s.accept(): "Connection found, putting connection into queue...".

Comment: @MarkTolonen Thank you for pointing that out! I made the correction, updated the question, and tested the code. The correction you made functions as expected but I am still running into the same issue

Comment: @BlackBeans I believe that there is based on successful ping and my team documentation. Another team member manages the device sending connection requests so I will check with him and edit this comment if I find something.

Comment: What is `HOST` defined as?

Comment: @MarkTolonen I added a sample HOST and PORT configuration to the question on your request. HOST is defined as a static IPv4 address and PORT is defined as a static port number.

Comment: I wanted to know the exact value.  You should normally be using INADDR_ANY ('0.0.0.0' or just '') to listen on all available interfaces in the server.  If you are hanging on `accept`, that means the client is not reaching the server.  You could be listening on an invalid address. binding to the wrong interface in a server with multiple interfaces,  the client is using the wrong address, or a firewall is blocking it.

Comment: @WilliamHuynh that's pretty strange. You should be able to test your code (at least its very basic features such as accepting a connection). It's as simple as creating a connection to the socket with `socket.connect`.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the help. After applying the corrections listed in the comments and troubleshooting BOTH the host and client ends of the connection the socket was able to receive connections.